# Why different Logout options coming

Tags: linux, debian, xfce, logout

I am working on Debian Stable Linux with XFCE desktop, which is otherwise working very well.

I find that when I click "Log Out" button on XFCE main menu, it usually shows me following 7 options:

[image]

However, at other times, only 5 options are shown:

[image]

Options "Hibernate" and "Hybrid Sleep" are not coming.

It seems to occur randomly and I am not able to connect this with any application or activity on the system.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Edit1: Following is output of 'free -m' command showing memory and swap in megabytes:

```
$ free -m 
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            3830         765        1839         229        1224        2610
Swap:           7950           0        7950
```

Edit2:
I also have Windows-7 on this system (dual boot) and I sometimes run it. Can that have an effect?

Comment: Ubuntu works the same way and what you get depends on what you start with (Logout, Restart or Shut down). I just use the function carefully in Ubuntu and rarely have an issue.

Comment: Ubuntu is based on Debian and function is similar.

Answer (score 2):

"Hibernate" is most likely not shown when your current RAM+swap usage is too high, so the hibernation image (which is the compressed RAM contents) could not fit into the allocated swap space. Check the memory usage using something like `htop`.

"Hybrid Sleep" is based on hibernation, so it would be not shown for the same reason.

Comment: I suppose available / unoccupied swap space is a better way to put it. (That is, allocated swap space minus swap space in use.)

Comment: I have added output of `free -m` command in my question. Lot of memory and swap space is available. Does this fit with your answer?

Comment: @rnso Was the screenshot taken when only 5 buttons appeared?

Comment: After above command output 7 buttons appeared.

Comment: I also have Windows-7 on this system (dual boot) and I sometimes run it. Can that have an effect?

Comment: Dual boot doesn't matter. user1686's theory is that 5 buttons appear when you're short on RAM. You took the screenshot when 7 buttons appeared, so that doesn't tell us anything about that situation.